ブラウザで http://127.0.0.1:5000 にアクセスしても「このページに到達できません」と接続が拒否される
ブラウザで http://127.0.0.1:5000/ にアクセスすると、「Hello, Flask!」と表示されるはずが、下記のようなメッセージが表示されました。
申し訳ございません。このページに到達できません
127.0.0.1 により、接続が拒否されました。

ファイル等の構成

app.py: Flaskアプリケーションのメインファイル
templates: テンプレートファイルを置くディレクトリ
index.html: 最初のページのHTML

app.py
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>初めてのFlaskアプリ</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello, Flask!</h1>
    <p>これは、Flaskで作成した最初のページです。</p>
</body>
</html>

アプリケーションの実行
python app.py


「下記のようなメッセージが表示されました。」はブラウザに表示されたのですか？アプリのログにエラーは記録されていませんか？

プログラム、もしくは起動時にポート: 5000 で待ち受けるような指定が不足しているのが原因に見えます。
参考:
https://www.tohoho-web.com/ex/flask.html#hello_world

他ホストからの接続を受け付ける場合は -h 0.0.0.0 を、ポートを指定するには -p port を指定します。--reload をつけるとプログラム修正時に自動的にリロードします。
$ flask run -h 0.0.0.0 -p 5000

プログラムに下記を追加して
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000, debug=True)

下記の様に実行することもできます。
$ python3 hello.py



ありがとうございました。解決しました。
